# In which order the attribute value is available in a servlet, If the same attribute is present in multiple scopes

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

What is the order of precedence to retrieve attribute values in which the same attribute key is present in all the following scopes

1. Page
2. Request
3. Session
4. Application

For Example,

What will be the output of the following

```
<c:out value="test"/>
```

If the attribute is defined as

```
session.setAttribute("test", "Session");
request.setAttribute("test", "Request");
pageContext.setAttribute("test", "Page");
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always goes from the smaller scope to the broader scope: page, the request, the session, the application.

See [PageContext.findAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29).

So, in your example, "Page" will be displayed.